# Can't add to integer in array

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that counts the vowels in a string. When vowelsInString is printed, all the values stay at zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printfArray(int array[]);

int main()
{
    char stringToTest[] = {}, vowels[5] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int i, j, numOfVowels, vowelsInString[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    numOfVowels = 0;

    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%c", &stringToTest);

    for(i=0; i<sizeof(stringToTest); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(vowels); j++)
        {
            if(stringToTest[i] == vowels[j])
            {
                numOfVowels++;
                vowelsInString[j]++;
                printf("%d",vowelsInString[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    printfArray(vowelsInString);
}

void printfArray(int array[])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=sizeof(array); i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

It looks like it doesn't meet the if statement at line 20. Why?

```
if(stringToTest[i] == vowels[j])
```

Comment: How big do you think `stringToTest[]` is, given that you didn't specify a size and used an empty initializer?  Also, `%c` tells `scanf()` to read *a single `char`*, not a string.

Comment: You may find making `vowels` an `enum` makes life simpler. If you can use `string.h` functions, using a couple of *pointers* and `strpbrk` may also be attractive.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your program is not working is the way you declare `stringToTest`:

```
char stringToTest[] = {}; // This is not standard C
```

This declaration is a C extension that creates a zero-length array. When you take its size later on, you get zero ([demo](http://ideone.com/FM2zCy)), so the program never enters the loop.

To fix this, allocate `stringToTest` to some maximum size, and read with `%s` instead of `%c`:

```
char stringToTest[100];
...
scanf("%99s", stringToTest);
```

Use `strlen` instead of `sizeof` to get the actual length of the word entered by end user:

```
size_t len = strlen(stringToTest);
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    ...
```

`printfArray` also needs a fix, because `sizeof(array)` returns the size of pointer on your system. "Fixing" it the way you attempted, with `<=` in the `for` loop instead of the correct `<` "works" by accident, because the size of your array is five. You should be passing the size from `main`, like this:

```
void printfArray(int array[], size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `char stringToTest[] = {}` is not allowed in Standard C  (in which nothing ever has a `sizeof` `0`). The behaviour you demo would be a compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a very good answer to your immediate issue, if you consider defining the vowels as constants, you may shorten your code a bit while making the process a bit more readable. While there is nothing wrong with holding the vowels in an array to test against, specifying the vowels as constants, combined with a short `switch` provides another approach. (you can separate and track upper/lower case vowels if you wish). A quick alternative implementation that takes the string to test as the first argument (`"alligator"` as the default example if no string is given) could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { a, e, i, o, u };  /* these become global constants, don't reuse */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *st = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "alligator", *p = st;
    unsigned vowels[5] = {0}, sum = 0;

    for (; *p; p++) {  /* for each char in st, convert to lower */
        char c = ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z') ? *p | (1 << 5) : *p;
        switch (c) {
            case 'a' : vowels[a]++; break;  /* increment vowels */
            case 'e' : vowels[e]++; break;
            case 'i' : vowels[i]++; break;
            case 'o' : vowels[o]++; break;
            case 'u' : vowels[u]++; break;
        }
    }
    /* get total and print */
    sum = vowels[a] + vowels[e] + vowels[i] + vowels[o] + vowels[u];
    printf ("\n vowels in '%s'\n\n a or A : %2u\n e or E : %2u\n i or I : %2u\n"
            " o or O : %2u\n u or U : %2u\n -----------\n    total %2u\n", st, 
            vowels[a], vowels[e], vowels[i], vowels[o], vowels[u], sum);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vc "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog."

 vowels in 'The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.'

 a or A :  2
 e or E :  2
 i or I :  1
 o or O :  4
 u or U :  2
 -----------
    total 11
```

Just another way to *skin-the-cat*. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In general, I wouldn't recommend single character names for enum members...

Comment: Yes, I saw that, that's why I put the comment out to the right. You sure wouldn't want a `for (int i = 0;...` later.